# Setting variable width on d3 tree nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to create an Org Chart, which has some nodes with longer names.

I've managed to modify the width of longer nodes, but have trouble properly placing their children and the lines (paths) to their children.
I tried calculating myself with `determineChildXValue()`, but that didn't work properly.

Is there a way to initialize the tree with variable widths so it will take care of the calculations of translations for child nodes?

Currently, I'm initializing it with hard-coded node sizes:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);
```

I've replicated the behavior in [this example](https://jsbin.com/cazidexuxo/1/edit?html,js,output) - expand **Departments**, then **DEPARTMENT STORES** to see the overlap.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consulted a colleague who was able to build a proper fix:

- Define the `source` and `target` properties (before the `projection` is set) for the diagonal (paths)
- Track the `tierDisplacementX` and `cumulativeDisplacementX`

  - Use these when translating the positions of the child nodes and their paths

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinays84/wd9skuuo/) to see the working code.